# python interpolation takes a long time

Tags: python, scipy

I do an interpolation with scipy.interpolate.griddata in a 1000 x 1000 grid.
When I have a point-cloud with 1,000 (x,y,z)-values, calculation only takes a few seconds.
But now I have 1,000,000 values. So I created a loop to extract 1,000 values out of these 1,000,000 values, like this:

```
p = [...]
z = [...]
#p and z are my lists with 1,000,000 values
p_new = []
z_new = []
for i in range(1000000):
    if condition:
        #condition is True for about 1000 times
        p_new.append(p[i])
        z_new.append(z[i])
print 'loop finished'

points = np.array(p_new)
values = np.array(z_new)
grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
plt.imshow(grid_z1.T, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

`print len(p_new)` returns me `1000`, so my loop works as expected.
But after my loop finished, I canceled my program after 15minutes of waiting because nothing happened.

So finally my question is:
Why takes this calculation so long although in both cases (1000 values by default and 1000 values extracting them out of 1000000) I have the same number of values? In my output `loop finished` I can see that loop only takes about 10sec, so it should have nothing to do with my loop =/

Comment: do you require cubic interpolation?  using `method='linear'` will save time if cubic is not required

Comment: more or less. you're right, `method='linear'` only takes a few seconds, but cubic interpolation would be much better for me...

Comment: Is your condition random, or do you sort them somehow or what? That could be really relevant.

Comment: was your data structured/regular before?  maybe now that you've sampled here and there, it takes more time to interpolate between the larger intervals.

Comment: @atomic: my condition searches for a certain z-value (+/- a little offset): `if z[i] < h+offset and z[i] > h-offset:`   @Big Al: data is totally random. But in the first test, with 1000 values WITHOUT this loop, my data also was random.

Comment: how little is the offset? You could be making your cubic curve fitting get really, really flat, which could cause it to become ill-conditioned and take a lot more time to compute.

Comment: offset is 5% of the 'height' of my figure.

Comment: More information: I read both of my lists out of a .csv-file. Now I generated a new .csv-file filled with the 1000 values I got from my loop and then loaded this new file - so nothing different from the 1st case where I also loaded a 1000-values-file. But, surprise, it also takes a looong time to calculate, so your suggestion that the problem is the unstructed data look correct. So: How can I structure it better? Sort it by x-value?

Comment: @ Big Al: Yes, it has to be a filter by a certain z-value.

Comment: Original post said, "When I have a point-cloud with 1,000 (x,y,z)-values, calculation only takes a few seconds." Were these filtered by z-value as well?

Comment: @ Big Al: The 1,000 values point-cloud is as random as the 1,000,000 values point-cloud is. So no, this one wasn't filtered. Just the "new" 1000 values point-cloud is filtered by z (look at my next-to-last post)

Comment: what is xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax for the two 1000 point runs?  are they greatly different?

Comment: unfiltered 1000 points: (-1717.0, 1727.0, -1056.0, 2015.0) and filtered points: (-139.0, 138.0, -85.0, 162.0) so same relation inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything unusual going on here - as far as I can tell the time taken
to interpolate is roughly proportional to the number of elements in the point
cloud.

Here's some test data:

```
def fake_data(n):

    # xy coordinates for an n-by-n grid
    grid = np.indices((n,n),dtype=np.float32).reshape(2,-1).T

    # interpolated coordinates
    xy_i = grid.copy()
    # not monotonically increasing
    np.random.shuffle(xy_i)

    # values
    z = np.random.rand(n**2)

    # input coordinates
    xy = grid.copy()
    # not regularly gridded 
    xy += np.random.rand(*xy_i.shape)*0.25

    # pick n random points to use
    inc = np.random.choice(np.arange(n**2),(n,),replace=False)
    xy = grid[inc,:]
    z = z[inc]

    return xy, z, xy_i
```

[image]

For all three methods a log-log plot of *N* vs time is roughly a straight line,
with a slope of ~2, i.e. they all require *O(N^2)* time.

If, in your case, you see that the lines are not straight but deviate upwards
for large values of *N*, that might indicate that you're having some other problem, such as running out of memory and hitting the swap.